# how to use overloaded std::less for std::map

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following snippet:

```
typedef char OR[12];

class COR
{
   OR m_or;
public:
   COR(const char* or) { strcpy(m_or, or); }
   COR(const COR& o) { strcpy(m_or, o.m_or); }
   const char* GetOR() const { return m_or; }

#if 0 // I do not wish to use this as it will create a temporary object
   bool operator<(const COR& left, const COR& right) const 
   { return (strcmp(left.m_or, right.m_or) < 0); }
#endif
};

namespace std {
   template<>
   struct less<COR> {
       bool operator()(const COR& cor, const char* or) const 
       { return (strcmp(cor.GetOR(), or) < 0); }
   };
}
```

When I try this I get an error:
error: no matching function for call to `std::map<COR, SomeStruct*, std::less<COR>, std::allocator<std::pair<const COR, SomeStruct*> > >::find(const char*&)`

I do not want to use any method that involves comparison of two "COR" objects. I will have comparison of COR with const char*. Can you guys suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour because your specialization of `std::less` does not meet the standard library requirements for `std::less`.

Comment: In order to operate, `std::map` _must_ have a way of comparing two `key_type` objects. When it performs this comparison, no temporary objects are created. If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to find an element using a `const char*` rather than a `COR`. This is (unfortunately) not directly possible.

Comment: What is it about the construction of a temporary that worries you? (I find it hard to believe that it is causing a performance issue, for example).

Comment: Further, it will not in fact actually create a temporary object. The objects are passed by reference, which then causes a call to the library function with the arrays decayed to pointers.

Comment: @Karl: although he hasn't shown the code I think he has a `map<COR, something>`, and he'd like to call `my_map.find("foo")`. In the normal run of things, that argument expression `"foo"` results in a temporary instance of `COR` being passed to `map::find`. Mankarse is right though that constructing a temporary is just copying a few bytes. Those same bytes are going to be compared multiple times by `find`, so it's difficult to imagine what situations the copy becomes performance-critical.

Comment: Ok, well... in that case, the copy is being constructed by `std::map.find` and can't be avoided by anything done in user code anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Several methods:
Note: None of these generate extra copies as the values are always passed by reference (and since we  don't normally mutate an object on comparison pass by const reference).

#### Method 1:

```
class COR
{
   public:
   // 1: Make it a member function
   //    Thus you only specify the right hand side.
   //    The left is implicit.
   bool operator<(COR const& right) const 
   {
       return (strcmp(m_or, right.m_or) < 0);
   }
};
```

#### method 2:

```
class COR
{
   public:
   // 2: Make it a friend non member function
   //    Note: Just because I declare it here does not make it part of the class.
   //          This is a separate non member function
   //          The compiler makes the destinction because of the `friened`
   friend bool operator<(COR const& left, COR const& right) 
   {
       return (strcmp(left.m_or, right.m_or) < 0);
   }
};
```

#### Method 3:

```
class COR
{
    public:
    // Just an example. Just need some way for the functor to access members
    //                  In a way that will allow a strict weak ordering.
    bool test(COR const& right) const {return (strcmp(m_or, right.m_or) < 0);}
};

// Define a functor.
//        This is just a class with the operator() overloaded so that it can 
//        act like a function. You can make it do whatever you like but for
//        comparisons it will be passed two members of the container (accept by const
//        reference and make sure the functor is const member and things will go well).
struct CorTest
{
    bool operator()(COR const& left, COR const& right) const
    {
        return left.test(right);
    }
};

// When you declare the set you just pass as the second template parameter.
//  (or third if it is a map)
std::set<COR, CorTest>        mySet;
std::map<COR, int, CorTest>   myMap;
```

The method you use will depend on situation.
In most situations I would use method (1). If there is a special sort order I needed for a one off event that I want to use with a sorted container then I would use method (3). method (2) can be used as an alternative to method (1) and in some situations is better (but you need to provide more details about usage before I would say use this).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The question was specifically about std::less() and this answer gives a lot but that.

Comment: @iantonuk The answer is correct for the question. The comparison class `std::less` uses `operator<` internally to do the actual comparison of two objects. So to allow `std::map` to use the `std::less` comparator as a means of sorting you need to define an `operator<` for your class. The first two examples explain how this can be done. The third example shows how you can use an alternative to `std::less` by defining your own comparison operator. I hope this resolves your confusion.

Comment: Initially looking at overloading the std::less<>() itself; The answer should be something like
namespace std{
     template<>
     struct less<pci>
     {
       bool operator()(const pair<char,int>&a, const pair<char,int>&b)
       {
        return (a.first < b.first);
       }
     };
   } 
Your answer doesn't touch on overloading of std::less() which is in the title of the question and what it involves. There's no confusion, consider adding it.

Comment: @iantonuk Are you asking me to add an example of `template specialization of the class std::less`? Why don't you just add an answer with that example?

Comment: Sure, there's such answer already on on SO, but it would be worthwhile to add/link it here.Would do, your answer is pretty full already though it would make sense just to add it there.

Comment: @iantonuk No I don't think so. That would imply that I think it is a good idea and the people that have already voted also think it is a good idea.The methods explained in the answer are the best techniques to achieve what the OP was originally trying to do. I agree that there are alternative ways to achieve these effects but I would be doing a disservice by adding them to a good answer. You are free to add your own answer and try and gather support for this alternative.

Comment: "I think it is a good idea" and "other people think its a good idea" is never a valid logical argument and can't be used as basis for any discussion.

Comment: @iantonuk That's not my argument. Nor do I see how you got there unless you are being deliberately a troll. My argument is that by doing that example implies that I think it is a good idea. Which I don't. You are trying to give your idea weight by associate it with my answer. I think your idea is bad and don't want people to use it. So I would like you to generate your own answer and get it voted on.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you made a mistake - the arguments type of the [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) `operator()` must be identical. So, this works:

```
template <>
struct std::less<COR>
{
    bool operator()(const COR &a, const COR &b) const { return (strcmp(a.GetOR(), b.GetOR()) < 0); }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the new overloaded versions of find(), lower_bound(), and upper_bound() added in C++14.  They do exactly what you are asking for.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find