# Using implicit comparator with a map that has a struct as key in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I want to use a map of the standard libc++. So defining operator< for the key type is one solution to instante a map. I did it but it does not work.

I checked that operator< works (compilation and execution).

```
png_pixel p1, p2;
p1.red = 5; p2.red = 20; // init
if(p1 < p2)
  puts("true");
else
  puts("false");
```

That is the definition of operator<:

```
#include <tuple> // C++11

bool
operator<(const png_pixel& a, const png_pixel& b)
{
  return std::tie(a.red, a.green, a.blue, a.alpha) < std::tie(b.red, b.green, b.blue, b.alpha);
}
```

png_pixel is a struct defined like this:

```
// My source code code
typedef png::rgba_pixel png_pixel;

// libpng++ rgba_pixel.hpp http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/
namespace png
{
    template< typename T >
    struct basic_rgba_pixel
    {
        typedef pixel_traits< basic_rgba_pixel< T > > traits;

        basic_rgba_pixel()
            : red(0), green(0), blue(0), alpha(0)
        {
        }

        /**
         * \brief Constructs rgba_pixel object from \a red, \a green,
         * \a blue and \a alpha components passed as parameters.
         * Alpha defaults to full opacity.
         */
        basic_rgba_pixel(T red, T green, T blue,
                         T alpha = traits::get_alpha_filler())
            : red(red), green(green), blue(blue), alpha(alpha)
        {
        }

        T red;
        T green;
        T blue;
        T alpha;
    };

    typedef basic_rgba_pixel< byte > rgba_pixel;

    // other things
}
```

But when I try to use png_pixel as a key in a C++ map, GCC and Clang are not happy.

```
# GCC 4.9
error: no match for ‘operator<’
       (operand types are ‘const png::basic_rgba_pixel<unsigned char>’
       and ‘const png::basic_rgba_pixel<unsigned char>’)

# Clang 3.5
error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('const png::basic_rgba_pixel<unsigned char>'
      and 'const png::basic_rgba_pixel<unsigned char>')
```

If needed, the full source code is available in branch map-converter of https://gitlab.com/RyDroid/Libre2DCarRacingsSimulator
libpng++ is packaged at least in Debian as libpng++-dev.

Regards.

Comment: Is the declaration of the `operator<` function available at the point of creation of the `map`? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no 'map' in your sample code - provide a proper test case

Comment: I think it might be a namespace thing.  There's `png::basic_rgba_pixel`, `std::map`, and `::operator<`.  Three different namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator<` isn't in the template definition context of `std::less`, the default comparator of `std::map`, and in any event is likely hidden by the gazillion `operator<`s in `std` for ordinary unqualified lookup, so if it is to be used, it must be found by ADL. But it's not in the `png` namespace, the only associated namespace of `png::basic_rgba_pixel<unsigned char>`, so ADL doesn't find it either.

Write a comparator function object and pass that to `map`. You can also try putting it into the `png` namespace, but that feels more icky.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For people that does not what is ADL, like it was my case : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

For people that have the same problem, I follow method 3 of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849429/how-to-use-overloaded-stdless-for-stdmap